# 'Concurrency': a namespace with this name does not exist

Tags: c++-amp, concurrency-runtime

I am an amateur C# programmer who strayed into C++ because of a need for the C++ AMP technology for some heavy-duty number crunching.  Hence, my C++ programming skills are not very well developed.

For my first attempt at an actual program, I chose code based on a [Daniel Moth's April 2012 article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882446.aspx).  I cannot get it to build. I always get the error:

> C2871 ‘Concurrency’: a namespace with this name does not exist.

I know that the code was first written for Visual Studio 11, but I only had VS 2008 and VS 2010 on my machine.  So, I installed VS 2017 (version 15.9.4, .Net 4.7.03062). I started with an empty C++ project but had trouble with it. The best I could do, after I worked through all the things it didn’t recognize, was an error:

> C3861: ‘access’ identifier not found, line 2616 in file ‘amp.h’.

So I started again, this time with an empty Windows Console Application project.  Again, I had to tweak the code considerably to migrate from Visual Studio 11 to VS 2017, but ended up with code as shown below.

I tried what I could to find the source of the error. I targeted both x64 and x86, but it made no difference. I commented out line 5 and lines 21 – 27, and the code would build and execute. IntelliSense showed no problems, either with identifiers or syntax. In fact, the mouse-over info recognized the `Concurrency` constructs as such. I deliberately misspelled `Concurrency`, but IntelliSense caught that right away. I looked through the project properties with an eye toward a setting that needed to be changed to run AMP, but as I wasn’t even sure what I was looking for, I didn’t find anything.

I tried to find the name of the file in which `Concurrency` is defined, so that I could search my machine to see if it was there, and to add a path if it was, but was unsuccessful. I couldn’t even find the file name. I googled and pored through on-line sources and MS Docs, but no matter how I phrased my search questions, I didn’t find any answers.

The error says:

> Concurrency does not exist

which to me means it can’t find it, it’s not on the machine, or some build setting is preventing it from being used. Most of the on-line articles about writing AMP code say nothing about build settings. Does it not require anything different than a serially-coded project? Is it as simple as a missing reference? If so, where do I go to find it? With my limited experience, I don’t know what else to try.

My machine is a Win 7 SP1 box. The **KB2999226** bug fix has been installed. I didn’t install all of VS 2017 since I am only interested in C# and C++. Did I fail to install something I should have?

If this problem was addressed before, I couldn’t find it. So, any help would be appreciated.

```
1.   #include <amp.h>
2.   #include "pch.h"
3.   #include <iostream>
4.   #include <vector>
5.   using namespace Concurrency;
6.   
7.   int main() {
8.       const int M = 1024; const int N = 1024;            //row, col for vector 
9.       std::vector<int> vA(M*N); std::vector<int> vB(M*N); //vectors to add
10.      std::vector<int> vC(M*N);                          //vector for result
11.   
12.      for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { vA[i] = i; }         //populate vectors
13.      for (int j = N - 1; j >= 0; j--) { vB[j] = j; }
14.   
15.      for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {                      //serial version of
16.          for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {                  //matrix addition
17.              vC[i*N + j] = vA[i*N + j] + vB[i*N + j];   //using vectors
18.          }
19.      }
20.   
21.      extent<2> e(M, N);                         //uses AMP constructs but no
22.      array_view<int, 2> a(e, vA), b(e, vB);     //parallel functions invoked
23.      array_view<int, 2> c(e, vC); 
24.      index<2> idx(0, 0);
25.      for (idx[0] = 0; idx[0] < e[0]; idx[0]++) {
26.          for (idx[1] = 0; idx[1] < e[1]; idx[1]++) {
27.              c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
28.          }
29.      }
30.  // C2871   'Concurrency': a namespace with this name does not exist.  Line 5
31.  // Also C2065, C3861, C2062 for all Concurrency objects    Line 21 - Line 27
32.  }
33.
```

Comment: The article uses `using namespace concurrency;`. Note the lower-case `c`.

Comment: I tried both spellings, uppercase C, lower case c.  there was no difference.  I left it at  uppercase because the intelliSense info used the uppercase version.

Comment: Thank you to Kashif R for the edits.  It's much easier to read and understand.

Comment: @RickSmith is correct:  I need to ask a different question.

Comment: FYI, I placed the source in a project in VS Express 2015, Ver 14 Update 3, Win32, X86. I had to change `"pch.h"` to `"stdafx.h"`, but it compiled without error. When run (debug), It exited with code `0`, but with a number of warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With,

```
#include "amp.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace concurrency;
```

I get,

```
C2871   'concurrency': a namespace with this name does not exist
```

However, with,

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "amp.h"
using namespace concurrency;
```

there is no error.

I suggest moving `#include "amp.h"` as shown.

I also used both `concurrency` and `Concurrency`. There was no difference.

---

For the error `C3861: ‘access’ identifier not found, line 2616 in file ‘amp.h’.`

From the menu, select `Project`, then select `Properties`.

In the `Property Pages` window, under `C/C++`, select `All Options`, then select `Conformance mode`.

Change `Yes (/permissive-)` to `No`. Select `OK`.

Build the project and run.

> > By default, the /permissive- option is set in new projects created by Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and later versions. It is not set by default in earlier versions. When the option is set, the compiler generates diagnostic errors or warnings when non-standard language constructs are detected in your code, including some common bugs in pre-C++11 code.

More information may be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2017).

This suggests, to me, that `"amp.h"` is not conforming to the changes made to C++ 15.5. Thus it worked with C++ in VS 2015 14.0 (Update 3), then failed with C++ in VS 2017 15.9.5.

Comment: I reordered the  #include "amp.h" per your suggestion.  Instead of the C2871,  I got a C3861: ‘access’ identifier not found, line 2616 in file ‘amp.h’

Comment: The problem is with line 27, `c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];`. When commented out, there is no error.  I have been unable to identify the problem. I suggest you ask a new question regarding the `C3861` linking it to this question, however, when posting the code, do not include line numbers. This will make it easier for someone else to help. (After "pasting" the code, select the code, then press Ctrl+K to identify it as code.)