# Does C++Amp require GPU hardware before it will build / execute?

Tags: concurrency, c++-amp

After learning from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54298286/9170346) that my VS 2017 C++ AMP project was basically sound, that the error messages while correct were masking the real problem, and that the issue was  certain lines of code, I rewrote the code as below.  By commenting out various lines at a time, I learned that

---

```
extent<2> e(M,N);
index<2> idx(0,0);
```

---

will build and execute, that code like

---

```
array_view<int, 2> c(e, vC);  
for (idx[0] = 0; idx[0] < e[0]; idx[0]++)
```

---

will build but will throw an exception if run, and that code like

---

```
c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
```

---

will not even build.  Note that I have not as yet invoked any parallel functions. 
 This leads me to ask:  does Concurrency Runtime or C++ AMP require that GPU hardware be installed to build and/or execute properly?

My machine has two multi-core CPU processors, but the GPU hardware hasn't been installed yet.  Still, I thought I would be able to use the the parallelism constructs to take advantage of the processors I do have.

---

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "amp.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace Concurrency;

int main() {
    const int M = 1024; const int N = 1024;             //row, col for vector
    std::vector<int> vA(M*N); std::vector<int> vB(M*N); //vectors to add
    std::vector<int> vC(M*N);                           //vector for result

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { vA[i] = i; }          //populate vectors
    for (int j = N - 1; j >= 0; j--) { vB[j] = j; }

    extent<2> e(M, N);                      //uses AMP constructs but
    index<2> idx(0, 0);                     //no parallel functions invoked
    array_view<int, 2> a(e, vA), b(e, vB);              
    array_view<int, 2> c(e, vC);
    for (idx[0] = 0; idx[0] < e[0]; idx[0]++) {
        for (idx[1] = 0; idx[1] < e[1]; idx[1]++) {
            c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
            c(idx[0], idx[1]) = a(idx[0], idx[1]) + b(idx[0], idx[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, GPU hardware is not required. After starting a successfully compiled program, without GPU hardware, the system created a "software" GPU as shown in the output when debugging.

```
'Amp2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11ref.dll'. [...]
GPU Device Created.
```

I used the available GPU diagnostics tool to look at performance.

[image: CPU/GPU Utilization Chart]